# StrongSwan: Pushing DHCP Routes (code 121) to Windows 10 clients

Tags: dhcp, strongswan, routes

my Roadwarriors usually use the same network address as my company's network does (192.168.0.0/24). By default the Windows clients install a new route which routes all traffic with destination to 192.168.0.0/24 to the VPN network. So their own local network devices gets unreachable. To avoid that I have disabled that default behavior. So no client route gets installed at all.

For that reason I have to install the routes on my own. I tried to achieve that with the VPNs DHCP server (option 121) and the StrongSwan DHCPplugin. But it seems that the DHCPplugin only pushes the assigned IP address to the client and NOT the routes the DHCP server offers.

Does anybody know how to solve that problem? I need the strongswan server to push the DHCP routes to the clients as well.

Answer (score 0):

For windows clients, try using option code 249.

**Below config is for ISC-DHCP-Server**

```
option classless-routes-win code 249 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option classless-routes-win 24, 192,168,100, 192,168,1,1;
```